# How to create custom button in Android using XML Styles

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make this kind of button [same background & text] colors by using XML Styles

[image]

that's just for an example, i want to write some other texts, like: **About Me**

Still i am using button created by designer in Photoshop

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:contentDescription="AboutUs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/aboutus" />
```

**Note:** I need this kind of button in every size and shape

*I don't want to use any image in my Android App i want to make it using XML only*

Comment: Us an image like this and set that as background of your imageView.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Have you ever tried to create the background shape for any buttons?

Check this out below:

Below is the separated image from your image of a button.

[image]

Now, put that in your ImageButton for android:src "source" like so:

```
android:src="@drawable/twitter"
```

Now, just create shape of the ImageButton to have a black shader background.

```
android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
```

and the button_shape is the xml file in drawable resource:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#505050"/>
    <corners 
        android:radius="7dp" />

    <padding 
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#505050"/>

</shape>
```

Just try to implement it with this. You might need to change the color value as per your requirement.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try https://angrytools.com/android/button/ to create customs button's xml layouts declaratively and easily without writing.

Answer (score 127):

Copy-pasted from a recipe written by "Adrián Santalla" on androidcookbook.com:
https://www.androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3307

**1. Create an XML file that represents the button states**

Create an xml into drawable called 'button.xml' to name the button states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />
</selector>
```

**2. Create an XML file that represents each button state**

Create one xml file for each of the four button states. All of them should be under drawables folder. Let's follow the names set in the button.xml file.

button_enabled.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00CCFF"
        android:centerColor="#0000CC"
        android:endColor="#00CCFF"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
</shape>
```

button_focused.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#F7D358"
        android:centerColor="#DF7401"
        android:endColor="#F7D358"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
</shape>
```

button_pressed.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#0000CC"
        android:centerColor="#00CCFF"
        android:endColor="#0000CC"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
</shape>
```

button_disabled.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#F2F2F2"
        android:centerColor="#A4A4A4"
        android:endColor="#F2F2F2"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
</shape>
```

**3. Create an XML file that represents the button style**

Once you have created the files mentioned above, it's time to create your application button style. Now, you need to create a new XML file, called styles.xml (if you don't have it yet) where you can include more custom styles, into de values directory.

This file will contain the new button style of your application. You need to set your new button style features in it. Note that one of those features, the background of your new style, should be set with a reference to the button (button.xml) drawable that was created in the first step. To refer to the new button style we use the name attribute.

The example below show the content of the styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.2</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**4. Create an XML with your own custom application theme**

Finally, you need to override the default Android button style. For that, you need to create a new XML file, called themes.xml (if you don't have it yet), into the values directory and override the default Android button style.

The example below show the content of the themes.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="YourApplicationTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Hope you guys can have the same luck as I had with this, when I was looking for custom buttons. Enjoy.

Comment: Ok, got a better answer that certainly will help others. And about the answering an old topic, I feel that as I was looking for it, others might also do the same. The more complete is a topic, the faster developers can find a solution to their issues, at least I think like that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Good answer but any idea why the padding option is ignored?

Comment: Just FYI - Brother you might want to change the link's https to http - since that site no longer uses secured protocol.

Answer (score 21):

Have a look at [Styled Button](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button) it will surely help you.
There are lots examples please search on INTERNET.

eg:style

```
<style name="Widget.Button" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_dot</item>
</style>
```

you can use your selector instead of red_dot

red_dot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"  >

    <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    <size android:width="55dip"
        android:height="55dip"/>
</shape>
```

Button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        style="@style/Widget.Button"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: yes i knew but i need to implement same background and text color in my code

Comment: @Sneha do you mean the exact color in image you gave in your question?

Comment: @Sneha You have internet connection use it. you can find color code for that background color. Use Gru's answer to create image drawable with that color. search for the font which match your requirement and apply on that button thats it.

Comment: your link is pointing to xamarin. Thare are some differences which can create confusion (like, that's not even Java code)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#ffffffff"/>

   <size 
       android:width="@dimen/shape_circle_width"
        android:height="@dimen/shape_circle_height"/>
</shape>
```

1.add this in your drawable

2.set as background to your button

Comment: i know how to use shapes, but i need to implement same background and text color in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
<gradient android:startColor="#ffdd00"
    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:centerColor="#ffff" />

<corners android:radius="33dp"/>

<padding
    android:bottom="7dp"
    android:left="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do, if you want to make a custom button design.

**1st is:**
create a xml resource file in drawable folder (Example: btn_shape_rectangle.xml)
then copy and paste the code there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="16dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
    android:color="#fff"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000"
    />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**2nd is** go to your layout button where you want to implement this design. just link up it.
Example: 
android:background="@drawable/btn_shape_rectangle"

You can change shape color radius what design you want can do.

Hope it will works and help you. Happy Coding