# Border for button in Android

Tags: android, button, border

I am making the page exactly as in the image link given below
But I am not getting how can I achieve the golden border for the button get started, Please help
thank you

Link- http://cdn9.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-0-s-307x512.jpg

Comment: Set a background with that color for the button. and then add a 2dp or 3dp padding. you will get that effect.

Comment: just create a custom layout for the button using appropriate xml files.follow this link for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles

Comment: create drawable with shape rect and add use that color code for golden to set to border.

Comment: Use XML shape, stroke is the line around your view ^^ make it 1px or 2px

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a drawable shape in your drawable folder like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#eecc68" />
</shape>
```

and in your .xml put like below,

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in d begining i had understood a bit now i got some more, but can u please tell me what is this android:andle in gradient, and how do u get that as 270????

Comment: variation of color intensity in a direction represented by angle

Comment: but when I change it to something else it gives complete black colour, why so?

Comment: I changed the color codes but when i change that 270 to some other value it just comes back to normal, effects nulifies

Comment: Damn,how do you guys know stuff like this?