# Dialog colorpicker which only displays purchased colors

Tags: android, mysql, xml, dialog, color-picker

So, for the moment I am programming an application with a shop system, you gain credits by doing and can spend your credits in the shop for colors to change the layout of the app.
**Idea:**
In my ShopFragment is a FAB which opens a dialog when clicked, which should contain ONLY the colors already purchased set in ImageViews (if purchased or not is stored in a mysql table, 0 is not purchased and 1 is purchased) and when I click on one ImageView it should be like outlined and open another dialog if I would like to set this color as layout.

**The problem:**
I dont know how to make a dialog which works as colorpicker which contains ONLY the purchased colors, prefered in order. *Example 1:*
Available colors are red, blue, green, orange, purple, gold and pink, I bought only red so there should be only one ImageView in the dialog when I open it. *Example 2:* I bought red, green and pink. Now there should be only 3 ImageViews in the order red green and pink which I can click.

But how do I make them being **1.** displayed, **2.** being in the right order and **3.** being outlined when clicked on?

Thanks for your attention guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 & 2: Do it the other way around. Add all the colors to your layout and then set those which are not purchased to visibility `GONE`. This way you can control the order in xml which makes it very easy.

3: Use a custom selector background for your items, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848987/4388512

Comment: Thank you, I didn't mind about GONE, that was the missing piece!