# RadioButton styled as a normal button

Tags: android, android-styles, android-radiobutton

I'm trying to style my RadioButton as normal buttons and support color change on the buttons, with ripple effect when one of them is clicked.

What happens now, is that all buttons are grey, they ripple in purple when they are clicked but don't change their color to purple permenently - which is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Thisi s how he buttons look right now

[image]

**RadioButton in whatever.xml**

```
<RadioButton
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:id="@+id/product_size2"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="S"
    android:button="@null"
    android:textColor="@color/material_light_white"/>
```

**Relevant items in style.xml**

```
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/material_grey_700</item>
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/material_purple_500</item>
```

I want the buttons to stay purple when they are chosen - solution?

Comment: I think you should use a background state selector for this task

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: ok, will try with an answer

Comment: have you tried to create a custom xml style for the buttons with the different states it can have? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29848987/5348534

Comment: I saw these xml packed answers - I think there must be a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

`radiobutton_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/material_purple_500" />
      <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/material_grey_700" />
</selector>
```

And use it as a Background:

```
android:background="@drawable/radiobutton_background" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work, what happens is the background overlays the style, effectively killing the style (creates a cube with no elevation) and no ripple effect