# Trianguler Buttons in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-button

[Triangle Design Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT0hM.png)

Hi everyone. I want to draw buttons like as shown in image.
What is best to draw triangle buttons XML or Java Code for multi support screen?

Comment: You Should Use Drawable.

Comment: can this link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles?

Comment: go for the drawable, it will be of less size and will ofcourse support multiple screen

Comment: ok thanks all .. can anyone plz forward some examples so that i can follow ?