# Android Studio how to make a custom button with soft Transparen background

Tags: android, android-studio, xaml, android-button, custom-button

I've tried using `Android Studio` to create a button with a blurry transparent background, as shown in this picture, but unfortunately, I do not know how to implement [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMTJ.png)

Here is a picture of how I imagine the button

[image]

Comment: Here is a picture of how I imagine the button https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMTJ.png

Comment: You can implement your own *drawable* (with different sizes for the button's background). This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles

Answer (score 0):

Use this library, you can create a blur layout and use it as button with setOnClickListener

https://github.com/CameraKit/blurkit-android