# How to extend AppCompatButton and inflate it with our own custom layout?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to do that? I have following code:

```
class MyButton : AppCompatButton {
    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        inflateView(attrs)
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
    defStyleAttr: Int,
    defStyleRes: Int)
    : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        inflateView(attrs)
    }

    fun inflateView(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_button, this, true)
    }
}
```

The inflate function gives me this error:

[image]

I understand that AppCompatButton is not inherited from ViewGroup, but what is the correct function?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Is it just a custom style for button?

Comment: Actually yes, Is it better to do in code level @Ircover?

Comment: I can't say it is a good practice to mention particular style in code, while it should be replaceable in xml layout or app style configuration. So I recommend to look [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848987/4762282).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I have been doing that for Android Java. So I am looking how to do it in Kotlin.